# How to prevent cron from spamming syslog?

Tags: linux, cron

I have a cronjob that has to be run every minute. And every minute cron add a new line into syslog about that. How can I suppress this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First, backup `syslog.conf`:**

```
sudo cp /etc/syslog.conf /etc/syslog.conf.backup
```

**Then, open up `syslog.conf` in your editor of choice, and change this:**

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
```

**to this:**

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none,cron.none          -/var/log/syslog
```

although the caveat is that you cannot check if your job is running.

Comment: I've also uncommented `cron.*  /var/log/cron.log` so I can check if my job is running :)

Answer (score 1):

redirect standard output into /dev/null, while if you going get an error you'll receive an email about it:

```
shell.script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: It's not the job itself that floods but cron just notifies that it did run it